# AdaBoost in Matlab - Only get 88% accuracy with Fisher's Iris data set while 100% in one layer Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, accuracy, adaboost

I have made AdaBoost in Matlab. I get 88% in accuracy when I use [Fisher's Iris](https://github.com/tjb1092/ML_SVM_SMO/blob/master/fisheriris.mat) flower set data.

Here is the working example:

```
data = load('fisheriris.mat');
X = data.meas;
y = strcmp(data.species,'setosa') * 2 - 1;

X_train = X(1:50, :);
y_train = y(1:50);
X_test = X(101:end, :);
y_test = y(101:end);

% Adaboost classification with 5 weak classifiers
N = 5;
[mode, accuracy] = adaboost(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, N);
fprintf('Accuracy AdaBoost: %.2f%%\n', accuracy * 100);
```

And here is the AdaBoost in Matlab. This will return back a model

```
function [models, accuracy] = adaboost(varargin)
  % Check if there is any input
  if(isempty(varargin))
    error('Missing inputs')
  end

  % Get the train data
  if(length(varargin) >= 1)
    X_train = varargin{1};
  else
    error('Missing train data')
  end

  % Get the test data
  if(length(varargin) >= 2)
    X_test = varargin{2};
  else
    error('Missing test data')
  end

  % Get the train labels
  if(length(varargin) >= 3)
    y_train = varargin{3};
  else
    error('Missing train labels y')
  end

  % Get the test labels
  if(length(varargin) >= 4)
    y_test = varargin{4};
  else
    error('Missing test labels y')
  end

  % Get the amount of models
  if(length(varargin) >= 5)
    N = varargin{5};
  else
    N = size(X_train, 2);
  end

  % Fit a model
  models = train(X_train, y_train, N);

  % Do prediction
  y_pred = predict(models, X_test, N);

  % Find the accuracy
  accuracy = procent(y_test, y_pred);
end

function models = train(X, y, N)
  % Get the size of the data
  [m, n] = size(X);

  % Create weights
  w = ones(m, 1) / m;

  % Create model
  models = {};

  % Begin the training
  for i = 1:N
    % Create a basic weak classifier, we choose a Decision Stump
    model.polarity = 1;
    model.feature_idx = [];
    model.threshold = [];
    model.alpha = [];

    % Declare the minimum error of the weak classifier as 1.0
    min_error = 1.0;

    % Iterate by finding the column that the weak classificer separates most
    for j = 1:n
      % Cut one row
      X_column = X(:, j);

      % Sorting, very important
      thresholds = unique(X_column);

      % Iterate the sorted row
      for threshold = thresholds'
        % Check which one that is below the threshold
        p = 1;
        predictions = ones(m, 1);
        predictions(X_column > threshold) = -1;

        % Which ones are missclassified

        misclassified = w(y == predictions);
        error = sum(misclassified);

        % Compte the error
        if error > 0.5
          error = 1 - error;
          p = -1;
        end

        % Update the model
        if error < min_error
          model.polarity = p;
          model.threshold = threshold;
          model.feature_idx = j;
          min_error = error;
        end
      end
    end

    % Compute the amount of say
    EPS = 1e-10;
    model.alpha = 0.5 * log((1.0 - min_error + EPS) / (min_error + EPS));

    % Do predictions and compute the new weights
    predictions = model_predict(model, X);
    w = w .* exp(-model.alpha * y .* predictions);
    w = w / sum(w);

    % Save the model
    models{i} = model;
  end
end

function y_pred = predict(models, X, N)
  clf_preds = zeros(size(X, 1), 1);
  for i = 1:N
    model = models{i};
    clf_preds = clf_preds + model.alpha * model_predict(model, X);
  end
  y_pred = sign(clf_preds);
end

function accuracy = procent(y, y_pred)
  accuracy = sum(y == y_pred) / length(y);
end

function predictions = model_predict(model, X)
  n_samples = size(X, 1);
  X_column = X(:, model.feature_idx);
  predictions = ones(n_samples, 1);
  if model.polarity == 1
    predictions(X_column < model.threshold) = -1;
  else
    predictions(X_column > model.threshold) = -1;
  end
end
```

**Result:**

I get 88% in accuracy with this AdaBoost model settings `N = 5`.

I trying with an `one-layer` neural network from [MataveID](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/MataveID/)

```
% Neural network - One layer
C = 1;
lambda = 1;
X_train = X([1:20 51:70 101:120], :);
y_train = y([1:20 51:70 101:120]);
X_test = X([21:50 71:100 121:150], :);
y_test = y([21:50 71:100 121:150]);
[weight, bias, activation_function] = mi.nn(X_train, y_train, C, lambda);

% Validate
y_pred = sign(X_test*weight' + bias);
accuracy = sum(y_test == y_pred) / length(y_test);
fprintf('Accuracy Neural Network: %.2f%%\n', accuracy * 100);
```

And I will get 100% accuracy.

**Question:**

Is the AdaBoost algorithm correctly written?
I mean...the one layer neural network is just one layer neural network with one activation function `sign`. AdaBoost is famous for handle nonlinear data perfectly and should be consider if the data is complex.

Comment: I would be skeptical of any model with perfect accuracy and not see that as a cause for celebration.

Comment: @Dave Notice that that NN has been trained by using Quadratic Programming. Also `fisheriris.mat` is lineary separable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boosting needs careful tuning of the number of trees to perform well, 5 trees seems unlikely to perform well.